# Solving recursive matrix system not fully correct

Tags: matrices, matrix-equations, recursion

I'm having a problem with a personal project in which I want to determine the dynamics of a population.

Suppose the following transition matrix is given by

\begin{equation}
T = \begin{pmatrix}
0.9 & 0 & 0 \\
0.05 & 0.95 & 0 \\
0.05 & 0.05 & 1
\end{pmatrix}
\end{equation}
The population is normally then determined by
\begin{equation}
P_{n} = TP_{n-1}
\end{equation}
However, in this problem the population at $n$ is determined by a different equation involving a sort of manual extra input matrix, i.e.
\begin{equation}
P_{n} = TP_{n-1} + S
\end{equation}
Now, this problem will differ from regular transition matrix problems (for as far as I know). After $n$ years, I want to have a pre-determined optimal population, say at $n=f$ (final year). Also, the starting population is of course known. We can now simulate this matrix system up to $n=f$ such that we can see whether we have reached the optimal population, say $P_f$. However, as this is interesing too, I want to solve this recursive matrix system for $S$ such that I find the suitable $S$ matrix such that after $n=f$ years the optimal population is obtained. I tried to do the following

\begin{align*}
P_{n} &= AP_{n-1} + S\\
&= A(AP_{n-2} + S) + S \\
&= A^2P_{n-2} + AS + S \\
&= A^2(AP_{n-3} + S) + AS + S \\
&= A^3P_{n-3} + A^2S + AS + S
\end{align*}
or phrased differently
\begin{align*}
P_{n} = A^n P_0 + \sum_{j=1}^n A^{j-1}S
\end{align*}
Then, simply solving for $S$ would yield

\begin{equation}
S = \bigg(\sum_{j=1}^n A^{j-1}\bigg)^{-1} \bigg(P_n - A^n P_0\bigg)
\end{equation}

However, when I try to simulate my answer, it does not seem to work completely. Suppose I have the following data

\begin{equation}
P_0 = \begin{pmatrix}
85 \\ 110 \\ 0
\end{pmatrix}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
T = \begin{pmatrix}
0.9 & 0 & 0 \\
0.05 & 0.95 & 0 \\
0.05 & 0.05 & 1
\end{pmatrix}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
P_f = P_4 = \begin{pmatrix}
80 \\ 130 \\ 0
\end{pmatrix}
\end{equation}

substituting the latter into our found solution yields

\begin{equation}
S = \begin{pmatrix}
7 \\ 10.8 \\ -1
\end{pmatrix}
\end{equation}
and running a simulation will yield 
\begin{equation}
P_4 = \begin{pmatrix} 80.000 \\ 145.564 \\ 3.68 \end{pmatrix} \neq P_f
\end{equation}
Only my the entry seems correct. The second does not. When I transpose the matrix, however, the first entry will become incorrect whereas the second entry will become correct. How is this possible? Is there a mistake or is my request simply not possible?

**EDIT:** My problem has been solved, and a numerical method in python can be found as the answer to this question. However, I also wanted to post my R-code for the people who are interested.

````
T_matrix = t(matrix(c(0.9,  0,    0,
                      0.05, 0.95, 0,
                      0.05, 0.05, 1), nrow=3))

P = matrix(c(85,110,0), nrow = 3)
GP = matrix(c(80,130,0), nrow = 3)

years <- 4
T_mat <- NULL
for (j in 1:years){
        T_mat[[j]] <- T_matrix%^%(j-1)
}

S  <- (Reduce("+", T_mat) %>% inv()) %*% (GP - T_matrix%^%years %*% P)

pop <- NULL
for(i in 1: (years+1)){
   if (i == 1){
        pop[[1]] <- P
   }else{
        pop[[i]] <- T_matrix %*% pop[[i-1]] + S  
   }
}

final_population <- pop[[years + 1]] %>% print()
```
````

Comment: That can't be right. Sums should be preserved, right? Rows or columns should sum to $1$ or $100\%$.

Comment: @mathreadler The columns should sum to 1, the 0.95 shouldve been a 0.9. A typo, has been changed. Thanks

Comment: So the typo was only in the text and not also in calculations?

Comment: Yes, unfortunately, indeed

Comment: You have written two different matrices, and called them both $T$. Bad idea. The first one is column-stochastic, the second one isn't any kind of stochastic (although it would be row-stochastic if the upper left entry were $.9$).

Comment: It's not wrong. This is the desired final population. Now, I want to manipulate $S$ in order to get to this specific $P$ at $n=4$. In this case, the transition matrix and the starting population (and thus the final one too) is known.

Comment: What does "run a simulation mean"? Is it iterating $P_n = T P_{n - 1} + S$ for $n = 4$ with $S$ given by $S = (7, 10.8, -1)$?

Comment: Any response to my comment, Rice?

Comment: @GerryMyerson True, and it has been changed. However, the problem still appears

Comment: @caverac yes, indeed!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must be making some sort of computational error.  I get a completely different value for $S$ that does produce the desired value when the iteration is run.

Here is my python script:

```
import numpy as np

T= np.array([[.9,0,0],[.05,.95,0],[.05,.05,1]])
P0 = np.array([85,110,0])
P4 = np.array([80,130,0])
A = sum(np.linalg.matrix_power(T, j) for j in range(4))
A1 = np.linalg.inv(A)
S=A1@(P4-np.linalg.matrix_power(T,4)@P0)
print("S=",S)

R = P0
for n in range(4):
    R= T@R+S
print("PF=",R)
```

This produces the output:

```
S= [7.04608898   6.74717393 -10.04326291]
PF= [8.00000000e+01  1.30000000e+02 -5.32907052e-15]
```

We see that `PF` agrees with the given value `P4` except for roundoff error.

It's impossible to say what your mistake is without seeing the details of your calculation.  The matrix algebra is correct.

Comment: Ah, I see what I did wrong. My programming was wrong. I thought my matrix algebra must have gone wrong, as my answers were not completely wrong as one of the terms was fully correct.

Comment: Later today I will add my code too! Thanks for sharing!

Comment: @Rice4000 You're welcome.  I made a lot of mistakes too.  I forgot that in numpy, $A**n$ doesn't mean the matrix power $A^n,$ so I got nonsense results.  But I knew that the algebra was right, so I kept working at it.  BTW, do you realize that $$I+A+A^2+\cdots+A^n=(A^{n+1}-I)(A  -I)^{-1}$$ when $A-I$ is invertible?  This doesn't help in this example though, since the matrix $T$ is column stochastic, so $1$ is an eigenvalue.

Comment: Yes, I did! However, as my $n$ is usually not that large, it also does not reduce computational effort that much. I forgot to use the matrix powers, instead I used element-wise powers.

Comment: @Rice4000 Same mistake I made, then.